# iPhone telephone api?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, jailbreak, telephony

Is it possible to access active calls on the iPhone (with or without jailbreak)?

Best,

Stefan

Answer (score 3):

An SDK developer (using approved APIs and no jailbreak) is pretty much completely sand-boxed off from everything to do with phone calls, except for the ability to send a dial URL to the Phone app.

Comment: The URL info can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html